# Sum vertically upto last empty cell on another column repeatedly

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Sum vertically upto last empty cell in **column A**
Show sum on the **first row** where the name resides on
***column B** **might contain 0 or more blank cells***

What I am willing to achieve is shown below

[image]

I have tried Using this formula `=IF(B28="",SUM(B29:INDEX(B29:B,MATCH(TRUE,(B29:B=""),0))),"")`
on column C, I am able to achieve close to similar result **but I have to keep single blank cell** before every name shown below
[image]

[Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGJuE510TQXuHm88F5Nki9a8d9lBAGXby7dkexIFkvw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: your sheet is view only, so i can't demo or test.  I will attempt to answer blindly.

Comment: I have corrected the sharing settings to editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arrayformula in cell E2 should work:

```
=Arrayformula(IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF(LOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER(ROW(A2:A),A2:A<>"")),LOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER(ROW(A2:A),A2:A<>"")),B2:B)))
```

The criteria and criterion arrays are made of a lookup that shows the last row number for any given row with a name in it.